# Two layers for loop in `JavaScript`

Tags: javascript

```js
function convertObjectToList(obj) {
  var innerArr= [];
  var outerArr=[];
  for (var prop in obj) {
    innerArr.push(prop);   
    innerArr.push(obj[prop]);  
    console.log(innerArr); 
    outerArr.push(innerArr); 
    console.log(outerArr);  
  } return outerArr;       
}

convertObjectToList({
  name: 'Holly',
  age: 35,
})
```

Can someone help me to figure out what happened inside the for loop?
**Q**: my question is on the second round: `outerArr[0]= [ ‘name’, ‘Holly’ ], but the console shows me outerArr[0]= [ ‘name’, ‘Holly’, ‘age’, 35 ]`

**Actual output**:
1. first round: `innerArr=[ ‘name’, ‘Holly’ ]  & outerArr = [ [ ‘name’, ‘Holly’ ] ]`
2. second round:
 `innerArr=[ ‘name’, ‘Holly’, ‘age’, 35 ] & outerArr=[ [ ‘name’, ‘Holly’, ‘age’, 35 ],[ ‘name’, ‘Holly’, ‘age’, 35 ] ]`

But I expeced: `outerArr= [ [ ‘name’, ‘Holly’ ], [ ‘name’, ‘Holly’, ‘age’, 35 ] ]`

Comment: outerArr contains a reference to innerArr, not a copy. If you need a copy, you can use `outerArr.push(innerArr.slice())`

Comment: Thank you! I got it! --  It only contains a reference NOT a copy -- hit my head!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new copy of the inner array in the loop.

```js
function convertObjectToList(obj) {
  var outerArr=[];
  var innerArr = [];
  var i = 0;
  for (var prop in obj) {
    innerArr = Array.slice(innerArr);
    innerArr.push(prop);   
    innerArr.push(obj[prop]);  
    outerArr.push(innerArr);
  } return outerArr;       
}

console.log(convertObjectToList({
  name: 'Holly',
  age: 35,
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use toString() to convert array to string then store it in outer array

```js
    function convertObjectToList(obj) {
      var innerArr = [];
      var outerArr = [];
      for (var prop in obj) {  
        var arry = []
        innerArr.push(prop.toString());
        innerArr.push(obj[prop].toString());   
        arry.push(innerArr.toString())
        outerArr.push(arry);       
      }
     
       console.log(outerArr);
      
      return outerArr;
    }

    convertObjectToList({
      name: 'Holly',
      age: 35,
    })
```

Actually  `for (var prop in obj) {}` is a foreach loop it will navigate through each element of the `obj` array

Comment: Thank you. but my question is why outerArr[0] will change from [ ‘name’, ‘Holly’ ] to [ ‘name’, ‘Holly’, ‘age’, 35 ], as forEach loop ran the second time?

Answer (score 0):

You are not pushing a deep copy of the array, but rather pushing the same array again. Each element of outerArr will contain the innerArr.
I think what you want to do is create a new innerArr for each iteration.

```js
function convertObjectToList(obj) {
  
  var outerArr=[];
  for (var prop in obj) {
    var innerArr= [];
    innerArr.push(prop);   
    innerArr.push(obj[prop]); 
    outerArr.push(innerArr);
  } return outerArr;       
}

convertObjectToList({
  name: 'Holly',
  age: 35,
})
```